# Extend Entity from vendor folder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sylius

I have an entity in `\vendor` folder, that I cannot change/touch, but when I use it in project, I need to add one more parameter to that object (`description`).

So I have code:

```
namespace SoftNation\Sylius\MyExtendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SoftNation\Sylius\ExtendBundle\Entity\ExtendTranslation;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="softnation_sylius_extend_translation")
 */
class MyExtendTranslation extends  ExtendTranslation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
     public function getDescription()
     {
          return $this->description;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $description
      */
     public function setDescription($description)
     {
         $this->description = $description;
     }
}
```

now when I try:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

I get next error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                       
The table with name 
'shop_beta_dev.softnation_sylius_extend_translation' already exists.
```

**All I want is that I can do:**

```
$extend = new ExtendTranslation;
$extend->setDescription('StackOverflowRocks');
```

Comment: Take a read through the FOSUserBundle.  It shows how to extend a User entity.  I forget what is all involved but the docs will walk you through it.

Comment: Does the ExtendTranslation class have Doctrine Entity annotations that define a table?   You get that error when there's two entities with the same table name declaration.

Comment: Maybe [the docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/index.html) can be of assistance? There's a section for extending models.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like @ccKep suggested ->
Check extending models here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html